# $XA=A^TX$ prove $X$ symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

> Let $A$ be a nonderogatory matrix. This means the characteristic polynomial and the minimal polynomial of $A$ are coincide. Or, equivalently, every matrix $X$ that satisfies $XA=AX$ can be written as a polynomial of $A$. If $AX=XA$ and $XA=A^TX$, prove that $X$ is a symmetric (complex) matrix.

So since $X=f(A)$ for some complex polynomial $f(x)$, from $XA=A^TX$ we can deduce $X^2=X^TX$, but only when $X$ is a real matrix, we can have $X$ is symmetric. I wonder if the original question is wrong, that we should add $X$ being a real matrix? I also check some low order nonderogatory matrices but fail to find a counterexample. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: So you have $AX = XA = A^T X$? I'm asking because the first part is missing in the question title, but is mentioned in the body.

Answer (score 2):

The hypothesis is that $A=SDS^{-1}$ with $D$ diagonal and all its diagonal entries distinct. From $AX=XA$, it follows that $X=SES^{-1}$ with $E$ diagonal.

The equality $XA=A^TX$ can be written as 
$$
SEDS^{-1}=S^{-T}DS^TSES^{-1}.
$$
Multiplying on the left by $S^T$ and on the right by $S$, we get 
$$
S^TSED=DS^TSE.
$$
For any $k$ such that $E_{kk}\ne0$, the entries in the above equality give us
$$
(S^TS)_{kj} D_{jj}=(S^T)_{kj}D_{kk}. 
$$
So, $E_{kk}\ne0$ and $k\ne j$ imply $(S^TS)_{kj}=0$.

Now, if $E_{kk}\ne0$ or $E_{jj}\ne0$, 
$$
(ES^TS)_{kj}=E_{kk}(S^TS)_{kj}=\delta_{kj}E_{kk}(S^TS)_{kk}
$$
$$
(S^TSE)_{kj}=(S^T)_{kj}E_{jj}=\delta_{kj}(S^TS)_{kk}E_{jj} 
$$
and then $(ES^TS)_{kj}=(S^TSE)_{kj}$. If $E_{kk}=E_{jj}=0$, we also get $(ES^TS)_{kj}=(S^TSE)_{kj}$. So 
$$
ES^TS=S^TSE.
$$
Multiply by $S^{-1}$ on the right, and by $S^{-T}$ on the left, to get 
$$
X^T=S^{-T}ES^T=SES^{-1}=X.
$$

Comment: Yes, but you proved a special case. Consider any Jordan block, it is a nonderogatory matirx but can't similar to diagonal matrix :(

Comment: You are right, but I think the argument survives even if  $D $ is a Jordan form with distinct eigenvalues in each block. I'll check sometime tomorrow.